# In oracle SQL DB same primary Id is present more then once with different batch_id. How can I know the batch ID just before the current batch ID

Tags: oracle

I am working on oracle database.
We load customer data in source table which eventually migrates to target table.
Every time customer data is loaded in source table it is having a unique batch_id.
If we want to update some field in customer table, then we again load the same customer in source table but this time with different batch_id.
Now I want to know batch_id of the customer just before the latest batch_id. 
Batch_id we take is usually the current date.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function

your sample data

```
select * from tab
order by 1,2

CUSTOMER_ID BATCH_ID           
----------- -------------------
          1 09.12.2019 00:00:00
          1 10.12.2019 00:00:00
          2 10.12.2019 00:00:00
```

`Row_number` assihns sequence number starting from 1 for each customer order descending on `BATCH_ID` - you are interested on  one  *before the latest*, i.e. the rows with the number 2.

```
with cust as (
select 
customer_id, batch_id,
row_number() over (partition by customer_id order by batch_id desc) rn
from tab)
select CUSTOMER_ID, BATCH_ID
from cust
where rn = 2;

CUSTOMER_ID BATCH_ID           
----------- -------------------
          1 09.12.2019 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're basically looking for the second biggest value in the `SOURCE` table.

In this example code the `SOURCE_TABLE` represents the table containing same `CUSTOMER_NO` with different `BATCH_NO`:

```
create table source_table (customer_no integer, batch_no date);

insert into source_table values ('1', SYSDATE-2);
insert into source_table values ('1', SYSDATE-1);
insert into source_table values ('1', SYSDATE);

SELECT batch_no
FROM (
  SELECT batch_no, row_number() over (order by batch_no desc) as row_num
  FROM source_table
) t
WHERE row_num = 2
```

Where row_num = 2 represents the second biggest value in the table.
The query returns SYSDATE-1.